# AWS Elastic Beanstalk deploy not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to AWS Eleastic Beanstalk. I'm trying to deploy a new application through awsebcli and I'm getting the following error:
"Error: OSError :: [WinError 145] The directory is not empty '.elasticbeanstalk\app_versions'

I was able to init the eb application. I am running the command line under administrator privileges.

Please Help.

Comment: can you list the commands you have run? what sort of application (node/ruby/python)? can you also include the contents your `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` file?

Comment: Sure, I created the application in the web interface(the application health is green) and I ran eb init in my sandbox. It is a PHP application and here is the config file:

branch-defaults:
  develop:
    environment: myapp
global:
  application_name: MyApp
  default_ec2_keyname: MyInstance
  default_platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.4 running PHP 5.6
  default_region: us-east-1
  profile: eb-cli
  sc: git

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

I've just ran into the same issue.

"eb deploy" temporarily creates a subfolder "app_versions" in the ".elasticbeanstalk" folder at the root of the project that contains the zip file to be uploaded to S3. Once done, the folder gets deleted. Check whether any software on your computer might be responsible for preventing this.

The cause for me was a files-syncing software (Dropbox-like) that was watching the entire project for file/folder changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing a Django Application and I get this message -

> Uploading app to S3. This may take a while. Upload Complete.

**How to fix every time it happens**

1. Disable/Pause file syncing applications, such as: Google Drive Sync/OneDrive/DropBox
2. Delete the (If exists) mysite.elasticbeanstalk\app_versions , don't worry, it's created each time you type "eb deploy"
3. Open Command prompt in the folder mysite\ and run the command

   `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Navigate mysite\ and run again `eb deploy` should work

The message I get when it's not working
[image]

The message I get when it's working
[image]